# How do I attach placeholder to the button through JS' DOM?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to figure out how to attach button 'Delete' to the each list element making so in advance that I will be able to make more buttons for additional list elements later.But when I create buttons,they appear without the text,just tiny rectangle box near the text.I wanted to fix through command `'document.getElementByClassName[list_number + "_button"].placeholder = "Delete"`,but I got an error even earlier trying to attach classnames to the buttons:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined
    at addButton (script.js:74)
    at script.js:82
```

But what's strange is that this error shows only at the [1] list object,not the the [0].For some reason with [0] object everything goes OK,although I didn't succeed in attaching name to it.I thought that the problem laid in list numeration,because the first button is actually "Send',but when I changed the value of `var list_number = 0` from 0 to 1,it only got worse and gave an error right away.

How do I attach text in the buttons so they will look normal?

*Note:the commands related to the buttons are at the end,everything earlier are command to add new elements to the list trhough input and make the elements line-through*

**CODE**

```js
var button = document.getElementById("button");
var modify_list = document.getElementById("userinput");
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");
var li = document.querySelectorAll("li");
var all_buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");

var i = 0; //Attach classes to the li
while (li.length > i) {
  li[i].classList.add(i);
  li[i].classList.add('done');
  li[i].classList.add('cursor');
  i++
}

//Toggle the line-through function(later we will cal the function that will toggle once more when clicked on element of the list.
var n = 0
while (li.length > n) {
  li[n].classList.toggle("done");
  n++
}

//Command to add new elements to the list and make line-thorugh when clicked.
function inputLength() {
  return modify_list.value.length;
}

function addToTheList() {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(modify_list.value));
  ul.appendChild(li);
  modify_list.value = '';
}

function addAfterClick() {
  if (inputLength() === 0) {
    alert("Please,don\'t enter the empty list");
  } else {
    addToTheList();
  }
}

function addAfterEnter(key) {
  if (key.keyCode === 13 && inputLength() > 0) {
    addToTheList();
  }
}

button.addEventListener("click", addAfterClick);

modify_list.addEventListener("keypress", addAfterEnter);


function toggle(number) {
  li[number].classList.toggle("done");
}

ul.addEventListener("click", whenClicked);

function whenClicked(event) {
  var li_number = event.target.className[0];
  //In JS it doesn't matter in some occasions if it's a string or number,I suppouse.
  // var li_number = Number(li_number_string);
  // console.log(li_number);
  toggle(li_number);
}



// Create buttons and their functions

function addButton(list_number) {
  var button = document.createElement("button");
  li[list_number].appendChild(button); //append button near the respective li objects
  all_buttons[list_number].classList.add(list_number + "_button") //create class for the button
  console.log(all_buttons[list_number].classList);
  // document.getElementByClassName[list_number + "_button"].placeholder = "Delete"
}

var list_number = 0 // because under number 0 we have "Send" button

while (li.length > list_number) {
  addButton(list_number);
  list_number++;
}
// console.log(list_number);
```

```css
.done {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

.cursor {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>DOM</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>What plans do I have till the end of the summer?</h1>
  <p>They are:</p>
  <input type="text" name="add activities" id="userinput" placeholder="add activities">
  <button id="button">Send</button>
  <ul>
    <li>Learn German</li>
    <li>Learn Japanese</li>
    <li>Learn Java Script</li>
    <li>Physical activities</li>
  </ul>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You're using the same variable `list_number` as the index into `li` and `all_buttons`. What sense does that make?

Comment: Creating a new button doesn't add it to the `all_buttons` list.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you,I got the problem.But I used different variables,they just look alike(li_number and lisr_number).Quite confusing,wont do in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text you want to be displayed on a programatically generated HTMLButtonElement can be set using it's **.innerText** property. The **.placeholder** property serves a different purpose.

Let's take a closer look at your **addButton** function:

```
function addButton(list_number){
    var button = document.createElement("button");
    li[list_number].appendChild(button); //append button near the respective li objects
    all_buttons[list_number].classList.add(list_number + "_button") //create class for the button
    console.log(all_buttons[list_number].classList);
    // document.getElementByClassName[list_number + "_button"].placeholder = "Delete"
}
```

The first two lines are okay. Trouble starts here:

```
all_buttons[list_number].classList.add(list_number + "_button");
```

**all_buttons** is a HTML collection of buttons you initialized before you started adding dynamically generated button elements to the DOM thus it just contains the buttons set up via HTML. That means this array is outdated and would need to be updated every time you add or remove buttons.

Furthermore you don't need to use that array at all if you want to manipulate properties of your freshly generated button - you can directly access it using the variable **button**. I'd also recommend giving those buttons an unique id, so you can reference them later on and give it a click event listener for example. Also since there is already a global variable named button you should give the variable inside the function a different name e.g. **localButton**.

Here's an example:

```js
var button = document.getElementById("button");
var modify_list = document.getElementById("userinput");
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");
var li = document.querySelectorAll("li");
var all_buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");

var i = 0; //Attach classes to the li
while (li.length > i) {
  li[i].classList.add(i);
  li[i].classList.add('done');
  li[i].classList.add('cursor');
  i++
}

//Toggle the line-through function(later we will cal the function that will toggle once more when clicked on element of the list.
var n = 0;
while (li.length > n) {
  li[n].classList.toggle("done");
  n++;
}

//Command to add new elements to the list and make line-thorugh when  clicked.
function inputLength() {
  return modify_list.value.length;
}

function addToTheList() {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(modify_list.value));
  ul.appendChild(li);
  modify_list.value = '';
}

function addAfterClick() {
  if (inputLength() === 0) {
    alert("Please,don\'t enter the empty list");
  } else {
    addToTheList();
  }
}

function addAfterEnter(key) {
  if (key.keyCode === 13 && inputLength() > 0) {
    addToTheList();
  }
}

button.addEventListener("click", addAfterClick);

modify_list.addEventListener("keypress", addAfterEnter);


function toggle(number) {
  li[number].classList.toggle("done");
}

ul.addEventListener("click", whenClicked);

function whenClicked(event) {
  var li_number = event.target.className[0];
  //In JS it doesn't matter in some occasions if it's a string or number,I suppouse.
  // var li_number = Number(li_number_string);
  // console.log(li_number);
  toggle(li_number);
}



// Create buttons and their functions

function addButton(list_number) {
  var localButton = document.createElement("button");
  localButton.innerText = "Delete";
  localButton.id = "myButton" + list_number;
  li[list_number].appendChild(localButton);
}

var list_number = 0 // because under number 0 we have "Send" button

while (li.length > list_number) {
  addButton(list_number);
  list_number++;
}
```

```css
.done {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

.cursor {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<h1>What plans do I have till the end of the summer?</h1>
<p>They are:</p>
<input type="text" name="add activities" id="userinput" placeholder="add activities">
<button id="button">Send</button>
<ul>
  <li>Learn German</li>
  <li>Learn Japanese</li>
  <li>Learn Java Script</li>
  <li>Physical activities</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: I don't agree with the recommendation to give dynamically-created elements a unique ID. If they're being created dynamically, you don't usually need to search for them by ID, but instead using some dynamic mechanism (e.g. `this` in the event listener, or by index in a collection).

Comment: @Barmar,sorry,but I didn't quite get it,maybe because I've just started with DOM and JS.I shouldn't use ID and class with array is even worse.Can you send link in the comments about what you mean?It's the first time I hear that and I suppouse it will be very useful in the future.

Comment: @EndOfTheGlory IDs are useful for accessing specific elements that are in the static HTML, usually using hard-coded IDs in the JavaScript. If you're adding them dynamically, you won't have JS that contains a known ID, so you don't need to give them an ID. If the ID is something like `myButton3`, you can add the element to `all_buttons` and use `all_buttons[4]`.